# Troubles uninstalling .net 6

Tags: .net, .net-core

How to actually remove .net 6 SDK?

*I don't want to go back to .net 5 (trust me) but I have to for some VS licensing issues at work.*

Before I start, I run `dotnet --version` and it returns 6.x as expected

**Windows Apps & Features** shows older SDKs, but NOT 6. I uninstalled all older SDKs with no problems.

`dotnet --version` still returns 6.x

Microsoft points me to the **.NET Uninstall Tool** which says it cannot uninstall SDKs installed with VS 2019 or later (and .NET 6 comes with VS 2022). So, that tool cannot be used although I didn't actually TRY it.

Went to **Visual Studio Installer** / Modify. I unchecked SDK 6, and *checked* 5 (I just want 5, nothing later). I completed that, and now re-opening Visual Studio Installer shows I  now have 5 and not 6. And Windows Apps & Features still says nothing about 6, but does show I have 5 installed. All good right?!

`dotnet --version` still returns 6.x

What am I missing?